# Trying to implement jQuery tabs in .NET Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am attempting to implement [this simple example](https://jqueryui.com/tabs/). However, the Javascript isn't working (all the content is showing at all times, no tab 'switching' is occurring). **All the JS files are hosted locally.**

In my head content placeholder:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui.css">
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // not working
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    });
</script>
```

In my main body content placeholder:

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Dos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Drei</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Blah blah blah.</p>
    </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Blah some more.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Blah again.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

So far from searching SO and wherever else Google has taken me, this is what I've found and tried (with results for each listed):

- **Wrap the jQuery code in `$(document).ready(function () { // code here });` rather than a simple function (`$(function() { $( "#tabs" ).tabs(); });`).** It doesn't work either way.
- **Instead of `$("#tabs").tabs();`, use `$("#<%= tabs.ClientID %>").tabs();` so that .NET can get the ID of the html element.** In addition to *not* working, this also produces the error: `tabs does not exist in the current context`.
- **Place the JavaScript in the same content placeholder as the #tabs div tags.** Still doesn't work.
- **Add `runat="server"` to the #tabs div tag.** Still doesn't work.
- **Delete the designer file, then right click on the aspx file and select "Convert to Web Application".** This doesn't work because this is *already* a web application and there is no designer file.

I can't figure out what else to do to make it work.

**UPDATE:** I was asked to view my browser console logs and found the following:

- One of the JS files is giving a `HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized` error. I noticed it was blocked and I unblocked it from the file system, but it still isn't working.

Comment: Are there are errors or 404's in the browser console?

Comment: Only if you have `runat="server"` on the tags would you need to do `$("#<%= tabs.ClientID %>").tabs();`.

Comment: Your Javascript works - see [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DAC84/5ezQW/) . I would suggest checking that all of the JS is loading correctly in the network tab in the browser. Also check the ID of the DIV hasn't been changed if you're using Web Forms.

Comment: @DAC84 there are some 404's for missing png files, but these should have no impact on the JS. The JS code just has 304's (content not modified), which is normal.

Comment: @DAC84 hmm there are some 401 unauthorized errors for the JS files in the JS browser console log.

Comment: arg... those files were blocked. I cleared the block but still not working.

Comment: Add a console.log line above `$("#tabs").tabs();` to see if it is being hit, I suspect it isn't. Try this: `console.log(jQuery.isFunction(jQuery.tabs));` to check if UI Tabs has been loaded.

Comment: @DAC84 added that but don't see anything in the log.

Comment: Something has broken before that line then. I think one of your local files isn't loading properly. Try the answer below in swapping out your local files for remote copies of jQuery and jQuery UI just to rule it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem could be in path to the jquery scripts.

Try to check loading of resources in browser console, or you can try to include jquery from jquery server...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: I've hosted all of the JS locally.

Comment: For whatever reason, this wasn't working locally, loading them from their works. Thanks.